# How to access the value of an Object type from a Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am implementing a function in firebase, whose code is as follows:

```
exports.sendMessageNotification = functions.database.ref('/FDSF/arbitros/{arbitroID}/').onWrite((event) => {

let eventSnapshot = event.data;
let nombre = eventSnapshot.child('nombre');
if (nombre.changed()) {
  console.log('nombre'+ nombre);
}

admin.messaging().sendToTopic ...});
```

In my database, 'nombre' is a child in the structure FDSF/arbitros/{arbitrosID}/

When I analyze the output obtained by console in the registry of the function, I obtain the following:
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeHwc.png)

My question is, how can I access the value of the 'nombre' object when creating a new entry in the path described above?

Thanks!!

Comment: It isn't clear what the 'name' object is that you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event.data is a [DeltaSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot) object, and its child() method also returns a DeltaSnapshot.  To get the data from a DeltaSnapshot, use its [val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot) method.

```
let nombre = eventSnapshot.child('nombre').val();
```